# What is stripe connect in layman terms?

Tags: stripe-connect

I need to use stripe connect in one of my projects but I have no idea what the difference is between the `stripe connect` and normal `stripe`!

Can someone please explain this for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Stripe you get *your* Stripe account, which allows *you* to take payments and eventually accept payouts on *your* bank account. With Stripe Connect you can connect *your* Stripe account to *somebody else's* Stripe account, which allows you to have some amount of control over that account. For instance you can make Stripe-internal transfers to or from that account.

For example, if you're a cloud software vendor and people do business on your site (e.g. Ebay, Patreon etc.), you have your Stripe account, sellers on your site each have their own Stripe accounts all connected to yours, and you transfer money into their accounts which they can then get paid out to their real bank accounts from there.

Comment: nice one. that explained it very well... This answer needs to be protected by the community as there are no other information as clear as this out there.